# C#: How to add just the values of a 2D array to a dynamically-sized list?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, list

I need to create a dynamically sized list that contains pairs of points for a window's form using C#. The list size will change depending on the data that is loaded.
A simplified version of my approach, to simply convey the problem, is as follows (in the real app, the for-loops will iterate over sizes dependent on loaded data):

```
        int[,] dummyInt = new int[1, 2];
        List<int[,]> test = new List<int[,]>();


        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            dummyInt[0, 0] = i;
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                dummyInt[0, 1] = j;
                test.Add(dummyInt);
            }
        }

        //Show the values in the list for debugging
        foreach (int[,] value in test)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(value.ToString("G"));
        }
```

Using this approach, all 500 values in the list are [99,4].

What I was expecting/hoping to get was

value 1 [0,0]

value 2 [0,1]

...

value 500 [99,4]

Seems like the list is storing the actual variable, and then changing the value with every iteration of the for loop. How can I store just the value of dummyInt as a new object to the list?

I searched for this, but I'm not sure I know the appropriate vocabulary to nail down the search.

Comment: You're effectively adding a reference, instantiate a new `int[,]` instead, then add it to the list.

Comment: "dynamically sized list that contains pairs of points", but instead of this you declare List of 2d arrays. `List<Tuple<int,int>> ` is what it looks like it should be

Comment: There are tons of questions discussing fact that "C# list adds same elements always". I've used one as duplicate that looks close to what you are doing, but feel free to search https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%20list%20add%20changes%20last%20object more if you want post to be closed with  different duplicate

Comment: I figured there would be answers out there, but after a fruitless half-hour of searching, I found nothing. I kept searching "c# list add value not reference", or something along those lines, and got nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your `List` object is storing reference to the `dummyInt` object. If you want to store different values in `List` you have to create new `int` array every time you are adding it to `List`.

Reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/4d43ts61(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: This was the simplest solution. Moving the declaration of dummyInt into the for-loop solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't need a 2-dimensional array if you're just storing a pair of coordinates. The first coordinate can go in the first element of a 1-dimensional array, and the second coordinate can go in the second element of the array. Secondly, the Clone method can be used to make a copy of an array object if you want to force a separate copy of the whole array to exist.

```
int[] dummyInt = new int[2];
List<int[]> test = new List<int[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   dummyInt[0] = i;
   for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
   {
      dummyInt[1] = j;
      test.Add((int[])dummyInt.Clone());
   }
}

foreach (int[] value in test)
{
   Console.WriteLine("({0},{1})", value[0], value[1]);
}
```

And finally, an array might not be the best way to store a pair of coordinates. You might want to use a tuple or make your own structure. If you use a Value type (struct) instead of a Reference type (class), you don't need to clone each one.

```
struct Pair
{
   public int x;
   public int y;
}

public class Test
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Pair dummyInt = new Pair();
      List<Pair> test = new List<Pair>();
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      {
         dummyInt.x = i;
         for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
         {
            dummyInt.y = j;
            test.Add(dummyInt);
         }
      }

      foreach (Pair value in test)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("({0},{1})", value.x, value.y);
      }
   }
}
```

Note how the result is different if you change the word `struct` at the beginning to `class`.

Comment: Your suggestions are appreciated. I'm very new with using C#. The only kind of programming I've ever really done (if it can be called programming) is using MATLAB, and I used that A LOT...and so, my mind thinks in matrices (2D arrays). The program I have for what I need to do works well in MATLAB, and I'm simply trying to translate it into C#.